# Scraping a page every time it changes

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

Hi I am currently looking to scrape a [age such as this "https://www.tennis24.com/match/ABiALWlt/#match-statistics;0" every time it changes score. currently i have the ability to scrape it using selenium and BS using the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
Chrom_path = r"C:\Users\Dan1\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chrom_path)
driver.get("https://www.tennis24.com/match/zVrM3ySQ/#match-statistics;0")

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("statTextGroup")
for d in data:
sub_data = d.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
assert len(sub_data)==3
for s_d in sub_data:
    print(s_d.get_attribute('class')[19:], s_d.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

but I have no idea how to automate it so that once the score at the top of the page located here"Medical timeout
6 : 6 ( 0 : 0 )" changes, the scraper scrapes the new data. the change to monitor though is only visible when the match is in play and not always there.

if you need anymore info please let me know and ill be happy to add it

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape in a while loop the "scoreboard"-class and when this is not the same as the old value of this then this value changed and you can scrape the other things you wanted.
Hope it helped

Comment: Thankyou for your assistance. How do i add that to my current code?